# Trouble adjusting constraints programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout

Hey I have a setup like this:

[image]

The left constraint is constant 111. I want to change this constraint to 20 and increase the length of the box. Currently I have:

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        view.removeConstraint(leadingConstraint)
        leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view.superview!, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: greenView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant:20)
        view.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)

    }
```

I originally had an error with `leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view.superview!, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: greenView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant:20)`. So I changed it to .Leading and .Leading for both attributes. Now the rectangle is stretching but it's not the correct size, it's going off the screen:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? (NOTE: I want to change these constraints by adding a new constraint not just simply changing the constant value. I'm trying to get a better understanding!). Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but a good suggestion for the future: Do not use `view.addConstraint(someConstraints)` ever! Instead use `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(someConstraints)` or `someConstraint.active = true`

Answer (score 1):

The way I should do is:

Storyboard:

- Create 2 constraints (one for the first state and one for the end one).
- Change the priority of each constraint. The first one must be higher than the second, but not 1000. Let's say 751 for the first and 749 for the second.
- Create an IBOutlet for each constraint.

Code:

- Change the priority of each constraint (firstConstraint.priority = 749, secondConstraint.priority = 751).
- Do a view.layoutIfNeeded().
- All these must be done in the main thread.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try use constant `-20` instead of `20` or exchange you views when you setup `leadingConstraint`.

Comment: Yes, change it to -20. And also you could activate/deactivate constraints instead of adding/removing them.